# What is the difference between "git rm *.log" vs "git rm \*.log"?

Tags: git

It is said that we need to quote the `*` in:

```
git rm \*.log
```

because Git has its internal file expansion.  But what's wrong or what's the difference between using that vs:

```
git rm *.log
```

or in another situation, something like

```
git rm log/*.log
```

if the shell expands it vs letting git expand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first (escaped) example is expanded by git, and will match against all tracked files whether or not they actually exist in the tree.  The second is expanded by the shell, and will only match files that exist.  So for example, doing `rm *.log; git rm *.log` will remove the files from your directory, but will **not** remove them from the git index.  In fact the "git rm" command will return an error because you didn't specify any files.

Comment: Bash, by default, will just pass `*.log` through if it finds no files matching `*.log`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use git, so this is more of a general line of thought.

Take a look at this:

```
stieber@gatekeeper:~$ echo *.cpp
Test1.cpp Test2.cpp Test.cpp
```

vs.

```
stieber@gatekeeper:~$ echo \*.cpp
*.cpp
```

Now, if "echo" were something that operated on a sourcecode repository, the first version would specifically address the files that exist in my working directory, which may or may not be the same list that the second version would use if the "git" software expands the wildcard. My working directory might just be a subset of the files that the sourcecode repository knows.

In many cases, the working directory should be pretty much what the repository has, in which case there should be no real difference, but you could also do things like "erase all those files" on a repository without first bothering to check them out (why would you, if you want to erase them anyway...)

Depending on how git treats pathnames, specifying a pattern with a pathname might be more of a difference: /*.cpp would specifically list the files in my root directory, which probably aren't part of any repository. Escaping this as /\*.cpp might instead tell the repository software to work on the matching files in whatever it uses as it's internal root.